# facebook username validation regex pattern

Tags: php, regex, facebook

i need a regex pattern to validate if a string is a valid facebook username?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to [this site](http://www.labnol.org/internet/username-for-facebook-profile/9025/)...

```
preg_match('/^[a-z\d.]{5,}$/i', $username);
```

Comment: It must also be at least five characters long.  Look for "Usernames also must be at least 5 characters long." under "The username I want is not available"

https://www.facebook.com/help/?page=897

Comment: Hey! Does the 5 characters long thing still apply? Because http://facebook.com/aol is AOL fan page. it's only 3 characters! hmm.. or is the 5 only for profile usernames? or is the AOL page name a special exemption Facebook made for AOL? hmm but it seems possible you can have less than 5.

Comment: hmm. Also it seems like /coke forwards to /cocacola odd. AOL and Coke are the only under 5 characters brand names I can think of at the moment.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/twc is another 3 character one. That one's for Time Warner Cable.

Comment: http://ericathas.tumblr.com/post/14569161971/the-9-facebook-employees-with-the-shortest-vanity-urls One letter usernames! So looks like `/^[a-z\d.]{1,}$/i` would be it. hmm. Maybe the short changes were after Dec 2010 since this is a older post. Just wanted to do some research/leave comments incase it helps anyone else.

Comment: It seems the general rule is that usernames must be at least 5 characters long, but exceptions can be made in certain situations, as in the case of an important brand.
http://www.facebook.com/help/105399436216001/

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern=/[~!@#$%^&<>]/;

var name=$username;

var count=0;

if(pattern.test(name) )
{
   alert('only characters');
}

if(name.match(/[0-9]/))
{

    count++;
   if(count>5)
   alert('not exceds 5 digits');
}
```

Comment: User tagged with `php`, but this looks more like JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you use javascript, I made a package and want to introduce you.

github.com/blue-hope/give-me-profile

you can get the regex like this way:

```js
import { SNSRegex, SNSList } from "give-me-profile";

SNSRegex(SNSList.FACEBOOK_USERNAME)
```

besides, I configured the regex : /^(?!.*.(?:com|net))[A-Z0-9.]{5,}$/i